# Segmentation fault in PCL viewer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ros2, pcl

I am currently working with ROS 2 humble on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.3 and a rosbag pointcloud.
However, now I am getting a **[ros2run] Segmentation fault** when I start my node.
I do only get the error, when I am trying to visualize the pointcloud with PCL 1.12.1. If I comment out the viewer, the fault is not occuring.
Do you have any ideas what might cause this problem and how I can fix it?

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

class SimplePointCloudSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    SimplePointCloudSubscriber() : Node("simple_point_cloud_subscriber")
    {
        subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
            "/velodyne_points", 10, 
            std::bind(&SimplePointCloudSubscriber::pointCloudCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

private:
    void pointCloudCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Received PointCloud2 message");
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());
        pcl::fromROSMsg(*msg, *cloud);
        viewer_.showCloud(cloud);
    }

    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr subscription_;
    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer_{"Simple Cloud Viewer"};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<SimplePointCloudSubscriber>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? Ubuntu 21.06 does not exist. Isn't Ubuntu 22.04 recommended for ROS 2 humble? Also, which PCL version are you using?

Comment: @IBitMyBytes you are right. I accidentally confused the version, I edited the post to include the correct version of Ubuntu (22.04) and PCL (1.12.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is likely this one:
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/5237
Tldr: there was a bug in VTK (dependency of PCL), easiest fix is using a newer version of PCL (at least PCL 1.13.0).